# GeoTIFF to NetCDF with time variable enabled

Tags: gdal, netcdf, netcdf4, nco, cdo-climate

I have thousand GeoTIFF files (monthly precipitation from 1981) and would like to convert it into single NetCDF with time dimension enabled.

I have read various similar thread in StackOverflow and GIS StackExchange, but could not find the best solution for my case, either the script is too complicated (I don't have programming skill) or the solution didn't cover time dimension enabled.

What I have done is:

- Convert all TIF in a folder to GRIB2 using GDAL: `for i in *.tif; do gdal_translate -of GRIB $i ../GRIB/$i.grb2; done`
- Convert GRIB2 to NetCDF using CDO: `for i in *.grb2; do cdo -r -f nc copy $i ../NetCDF/$i.nc; done`
- Merge all NC in a folder using NCO: `ncrcat *.nc merge.nc`
- Then check the file: `ncdump -h merge.nc` I got this

```
netcdf merge {
dimensions:
    time = UNLIMITED ; // (467 currently)
    lon = 920 ;
    lat = 339 ;
variables:
    double time(time) ;
        time:standard_name = "time" ;
        time:units = "minutes since 1970-1-1 00:00:00" ;
        time:calendar = "proleptic_gregorian" ;
        time:axis = "T" ;
    double lon(lon) ;
        lon:standard_name = "longitude" ;
        lon:long_name = "longitude" ;
        lon:units = "degrees_east" ;
        lon:axis = "X" ;
    double lat(lat) ;
        lat:standard_name = "latitude" ;
        lat:long_name = "latitude" ;
        lat:units = "degrees_north" ;
        lat:axis = "Y" ;
    float param255.255.0(time, lat, lon) ;

// global attributes:
        :CDI = "Climate Data Interface version 1.9.8 (https://mpimet.mpg.de/cdi)" ;
        :Conventions = "CF-1.6" ;
        :history = "Tue Jul  7 09:49:30 2020: ncrcat idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1981.01.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1981.02.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1981.03.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1981.04.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1981.05.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1981.06.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1981.07.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1981.08.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1981.09.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1981.10.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1981.11.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1981.12.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1982.01.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1982.02.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1982.03.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1982.04.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1982.05.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1982.06.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1982.07.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1982.08.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1982.09.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1982.10.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1982.11.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1982.12.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1983.01.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1983.02.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1983.03.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1983.04.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1983.05.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1983.06.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1983.07.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1983.08.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1983.09.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1983.10.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1983.11.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1983.12.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1984.01.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1984.02.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1984.03.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1984.04.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1984.05.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1984.06.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1984.07.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1984.08.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1984.09.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1984.10.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1984.11.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1984.12.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1985.01.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1985.02.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1985.03.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1985.04.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1985.05.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1985.06.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1985.07.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1985.08.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1985.09.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1985.10.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1985.11.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1985.12.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1986.01.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1986.02.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1986.03.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1986.04.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1986.05.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1986.06.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1986.07.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1986.08.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1986.09.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1986.10.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1986.11.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1986.12.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1987.01.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1987.02.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1987.03.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1987.04.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1987.05.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1987.06.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1987.07.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1987.08.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1987.09.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1987.10.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1987.11.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1987.12.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1988.01.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1988.02.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1988.03.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1988.04.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1988.05.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1988.06.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1988.07.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1988.08.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1988.09.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1988.10.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1988.11.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1988.12.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1989.01.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1989.02.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1989.03.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1989.04.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1989.05.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1989.06.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1989.07.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1989.08.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1989.09.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1989.10.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1989.11.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1989.12.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1990.01.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1990.02.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1990.03.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1990.04.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1990.05.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1990.06.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1990.07.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1990.08.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1990.09.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1990.10.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1990.11.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1990.12.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1991.01.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1991.02.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1991.03.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1991.04.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1991.05.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1991.06.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1991.07.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1991.08.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1991.09.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1991.10.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1991.11.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1992.01.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1992.02.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1992.03.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1992.04.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1992.05.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1992.06.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1992.07.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1992.08.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1992.09.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1992.10.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1992.11.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1992.12.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1993.01.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1993.02.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1993.03.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1993.04.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1993.05.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1993.06.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1993.07.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1993.08.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1993.09.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1993.10.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1993.11.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1993.12.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1994.01.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1994.02.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1994.03.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1994.04.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1994.05.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1994.06.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1994.07.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1994.08.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1994.09.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1994.10.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1994.11.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1994.12.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1995.01.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1995.02.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1995.03.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1995.04.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1995.05.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1995.06.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1995.07.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1995.08.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1995.09.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1995.10.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1995.11.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1995.12.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1996.01.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1996.02.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1996.03.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1996.04.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1996.05.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1996.06.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1996.07.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1996.08.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1996.09.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1996.10.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1996.11.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1996.12.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1997.01.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1997.02.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1997.03.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1997.04.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1997.05.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1997.06.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1997.07.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1997.08.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1997.09.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1997.10.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1997.11.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1997.12.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1998.01.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1998.02.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1998.03.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1998.04.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1998.05.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1998.06.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1998.07.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1998.08.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1998.09.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1998.10.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1998.11.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1998.12.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1999.01.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1999.02.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1999.03.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1999.04.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1999.05.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1999.06.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1999.07.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1999.08.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1999.09.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1999.10.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1999.11.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1999.12.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2000.01.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2000.02.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2000.03.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2000.04.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2000.05.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2000.06.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2000.07.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2000.08.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2000.09.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2000.10.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2000.11.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2000.12.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2001.01.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2001.02.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2001.03.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2001.04.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2001.05.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2001.06.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2001.07.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2001.08.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2001.09.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2001.10.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2001.11.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2001.12.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2002.01.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2002.02.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2002.03.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2002.04.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2002.05.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2002.06.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2002.07.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2002.08.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2002.09.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2002.10.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2002.11.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2002.12.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2003.01.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2003.02.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2003.03.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2003.04.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2003.05.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2003.06.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2003.07.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2003.08.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2003.09.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2003.10.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2003.11.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2003.12.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2004.01.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2004.02.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2004.03.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2004.04.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2004.05.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2004.06.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2004.07.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2004.08.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2004.09.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2004.10.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2004.11.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2004.12.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2005.01.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2005.02.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2005.03.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2005.04.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2005.05.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2005.06.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2005.07.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2005.08.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2005.09.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2005.10.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2005.11.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2005.12.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2006.01.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2006.02.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2006.05.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2006.06.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2006.07.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2006.08.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2006.09.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2006.10.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2006.11.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2006.12.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2007.01.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2007.02.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2007.03.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2007.04.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2007.05.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2007.06.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2007.07.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2007.08.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2007.09.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2007.10.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2007.11.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2007.12.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2008.01.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2008.02.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2008.03.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2008.04.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2008.05.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2008.06.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2008.07.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2008.08.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2008.09.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2008.10.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2008.11.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2008.12.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2009.01.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2009.02.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2009.03.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2009.04.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2009.05.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2009.06.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2009.07.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2009.08.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2009.09.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2009.10.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2009.11.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2009.12.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2010.01.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2010.02.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2010.03.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2010.04.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2010.05.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2010.06.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2010.07.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2010.08.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2010.09.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2010.10.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2010.11.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2010.12.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2011.01.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2011.02.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2011.03.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2011.04.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2011.05.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2011.06.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2011.07.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2011.08.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2011.09.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2011.10.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2011.11.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2011.12.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2012.01.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2012.02.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2012.03.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2012.04.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2012.05.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2012.06.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2012.07.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2012.08.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2012.09.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2012.10.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2012.11.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2012.12.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2013.01.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2013.02.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2013.03.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2013.04.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2013.05.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2013.06.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2013.07.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2013.08.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2013.09.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2013.10.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2013.11.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2013.12.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2014.01.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2014.02.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2014.03.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2014.04.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2014.05.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2014.06.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2014.07.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2014.08.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2014.09.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2014.10.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2014.11.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2014.12.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2015.01.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2015.02.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2015.03.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2015.04.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2015.06.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2015.07.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2015.08.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2015.09.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2015.10.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2015.11.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2015.12.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2016.01.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2016.02.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2016.03.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2016.04.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2016.05.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2016.06.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2016.07.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2016.08.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2016.09.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2016.10.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2016.11.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2016.12.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2017.01.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2017.02.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2017.03.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2017.04.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2017.05.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2017.06.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2017.07.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2017.08.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2017.09.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2017.10.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2017.11.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2017.12.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2018.01.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2018.02.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2018.03.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2018.04.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2018.05.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2018.06.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2018.07.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2018.08.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2018.09.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2018.10.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2018.11.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2018.12.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2019.01.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2019.02.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2019.03.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2019.05.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2019.06.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2019.07.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2019.08.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2019.09.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2019.10.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2019.11.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2019.12.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2020.01.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2020.02.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2020.03.tif.grb2.nc idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.2020.04.tif.grb2.nc merge.nc\n",
            "Tue Jul 07 09:38:36 2020: cdo -r -f nc copy idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1981.01.tif.grb2 ../NetCDF/idn_cli_chirps-v2.0.1981.01.tif.grb2.nc" ;
        :CDO = "Climate Data Operators version 1.9.8 (https://mpimet.mpg.de/cdo)" ;
        :NCO = "netCDF Operators version 4.9.3 (Homepage = http://nco.sf.net, Code = http://github.com/nco/nco)" ;
}
```

I would like to change the variable name and edit the content of `param255.255.0(time, lat, lon) ;` into something like below:

```
float precipitation(time,lat,lon) ;
    precipitation:_FIllValue = -9999.9f ;
    precipitation:_CodeMissingValue = "-9999.9f" ;
    precipitation:_DimensionNames = "time,lat,lon" ;
    precipitation:_Units = "mm/month" ;
    precipitation:_missing_values = -9999.9f ;
    precipitation:_units = "mm" ;
```

Is it possible using NCO or CDO? If yes, how to do that?
Is the process I have done above correct and make sense? Any recommendation are welcome.

When opening merge.nc in Panoply, I found all the date is 1970-01-01
How to make the date following the date that could be found in input filename?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way on how to convert a folder of CHIRPS GeoTIFF data to single NetCDF file with time dimension enabled that is [CF-Compliant](http://cfconventions.org/cf-conventions/v1.6.0/cf-conventions.html)

This is based on Rich Signell's answer on StackExchange: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/70487 and I modify it so can works using CHIRPS dekad data.
Adjustment is needed if using other timesteps data for CHIRPS. And [NCO](http://nco.sourceforge.net) must be installed before using this script.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
import os
import gdal
import netCDF4
import re

ds = gdal.Open('/path/to/dir/chirps-v2.0.1981.01.1.tif') # Data location
a = ds.ReadAsArray()
nlat,nlon = np.shape(a)

b = ds.GetGeoTransform() #bbox, interval
lon = np.arange(nlon)*b[1]+b[0]
lat = np.arange(nlat)*b[5]+b[3]

basedate = dt.datetime(1980,1,1,0,0,0)


# Create NetCDF file
nco = netCDF4.Dataset('chirps_dekads.nc','w',clobber=True) # Output name


# Chunking is optional, but can improve access a lot: 
# (see: http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/blogs/developer/entry/chunking_data_choosing_shapes)
chunk_lon=10
chunk_lat=10
chunk_time=12


# Create dimensions, variables and attributes:
nco.createDimension('lon',nlon)
nco.createDimension('lat',nlat)
nco.createDimension('time',None)

timeo = nco.createVariable('time','f4',('time'))
timeo.units = 'days since 1980-1-1 00:00:00'
timeo.standard_name = 'time'
timeo.calendar = 'gregorian'
timeo.axis = 'T'

lono = nco.createVariable('lon','f4',('lon'))
lono.units = 'degrees_east'
lono.standard_name = 'longitude'
lono.long_name = 'longitude'
lono.axis = 'X'

lato = nco.createVariable('lat','f4',('lat'))
lato.units = 'degrees_north'
lato.standard_name = 'latitude'
lato.long_name = 'latitude'
lato.axis = 'Y'

# Create container variable for CRS: lon/lat WGS84 datum
crso = nco.createVariable('crs','i4')
crso.long_name = 'Lon/Lat Coords in WGS84'
crso.grid_mapping_name='latitude_longitude'
crso.longitude_of_prime_meridian = 0.0
crso.semi_major_axis = 6378137.0
crso.inverse_flattening = 298.257223563

# Create float variable for precipitation data, with chunking
pcpo = nco.createVariable('precip', 'f4',  ('time', 'lat', 'lon'), 
   zlib=True,chunksizes=[chunk_time,chunk_lat,chunk_lon],fill_value=-9999.)
pcpo.units = 'mm'
pcpo.standard_name = 'convective precipitation rate'
pcpo.long_name = 'Climate Hazards group InfraRed Precipitation with Stations'
pcpo.time_step = 'dekad'
pcpo.missing_value = -9999.
pcpo.geospatial_lat_min = -50.
pcpo.geospatial_lat_max = 50.
pcpo.geospatial_lon_min = -180.
pcpo.geospatial_lon_max = 180.
pcpo.grid_mapping = 'crs'
pcpo.set_auto_maskandscale(False)

# Additional attributes
nco.Conventions='CF-1.6'
nco.title = "CHIRPS v2.0"
nco.history = "created by Climate Hazards Group. University of California at Santa Barbara"
nco.version = "Version 2.0"
nco.comments = "time variable denotes the first day of the given dekad."
nco.website = "https://www.chc.ucsb.edu/data/chirps"
nco.date_created = "2020-12-10"
nco.creator_name = "Ethan Hunt"
nco.creator_email = "ethan.hunt@mi6.imf"
nco.institution = "Impossible Mission Force"
nco.note = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua"


# Write lon,lat
lono[:]=lon
lato[:]=lat

pat = re.compile('chirps-v2.0.[0-9]{4}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{1}')
itime=0

# Step through data, writing time and data to NetCDF
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/path/to/dir/'):
    dirs.sort()
    files.sort()
    for f in files:
        if re.match(pat,f):
            # read the time values by parsing the filename
            year=int(f[12:16])
            mon=int(f[17:19])
            dekad=int(f[20:21])
            date=dt.datetime(year,mon,dekad,0,0,0)
            print(date)
            dtime=(date-basedate).total_seconds()/86400.
            timeo[itime]=dtime
           # precipitation
            pcp_path = os.path.join(root,f)
            print(pcp_path)
            pcp=gdal.Open(pcp_path)
            a=pcp.ReadAsArray()  #data
            pcpo[itime,:,:]=a
            itime=itime+1

nco.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you were willing to read the manual you could easily rename any variable with [ncrename](https://nco.sf.net/nco.html#ncrename) and add attributes to your heart's content with [ncatted](https://nco.sf.net/nco.html#ncatted).

Comment: Is it something like:
```ncrename -d param255.255.0,precipitation file.nc``` and then
```ncatted -a units,precipitation,modify,c,'mm' fileinput.nc```

Comment: Please behave more appropriately. Why are you asking this question? You have provided nco commands and asked if they work. There is one to way to try this. Run them yourself.